# I tried installing Bitcoin on a Ubuntu 18.4 server. The status of the Block is still in 0 even after two days of installation

Tags: ubuntu, installation

I tried installing Bitcoin on a Ubuntu 18.4 server. After installing the Bitcoin core, I started Bitcoin-diamond. The status of the Block is still in 0 even after two days of installation.

I want to know how long it will take to allocate the blocks?

Comment: Do you mean the Bitcoin Core daemon `bitcoind`?

Comment: What does "status of the block" mean?